# How do I use the access token to get email address and some basic info of facebook users

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the follwing code and would like to take the email address and other details of facebook user. This is the code that I have done.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
         //updateUserInfo(fb_id);
        console.log(response.authResponse);
        updateUserInfo(response.authResponse.userID);
        $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/'+response.authResponse.userID+'/ fields=id,name,birthday,email,gender,hometown,location',
           success: function(data){
                fb_data = data;
               console.log(data);
            }});
 },{scope:'email'});
```

I am unable to get get the following details:

1. birthday
2. email
3. Location
4. hometown

However, I am able to get the first name and id.

If I am supposed to use the access token, how am i supposed to put it in the query? The email address is the vital information as my system identifies user by email address.

Comment: If user are request their own, then they are require to grant the APP with email, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location permission for your case. If user are request for their friends, then friends_birthday, friends_hometown, friends_location should granted. To access friend's email, there's a known bug as discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630972/facebook-graph-api-wont-return-email-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use the ajax call after FB.login, you can use `FB.api` [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) , which will ensure that the access token that you have obtained while logging in (requiring email access) will be used for accessing the data

Answer (score 3):

You need following permission from user to get the data from Facebook.

1. **user_birthday** for  birthday
2. **email** for email
3. **user_location** for Location
4. **user_hometown** for hometown

You can [check this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) or [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/) for other permissions and uses.

Then you will get the access token once user click on your Login button and authorize your App.