# Cant get FBGraphUser email

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook login with my app. (Facebook iOS SDK version 3.11.1)

I ask for "email" permission:

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"basic_info", @"email", nil];
```

Most of the time, I do get the user's email like that:

```
NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
//user is (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *)
```

Sometimes I just don't. (I can see that the  NSDictionary is not including email).

I am using this fix so the app won't terminate when i use email later and its nil:

```
NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"] ? [user objectForKey:@"email"] : @"NO_EMAIL";
```

But i need the real mail, so i have to come up with a new solution.
I haven't noticed something special with the problematic users.
Any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: known bug for js SDK according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630972/facebook-graph-api-wont-return-email-address

Comment: possible duplicate of [Register with Facebook sometimes doesn't provide email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347104/register-with-facebook-sometimes-doesnt-provide-email)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that its a well known problem... For many reasons, not everyone on Facebook have Email address registered.

But as i said, my problem is that i need a real mail.
So the simplest solution is to use the user's Facebook Email : user_name@facebook.com

```
NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"] ? [user objectForKey:@"email"] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@facebook.com", user.username];
```

- some links ref to that you can't sent HTML emails to the Facebook mail, only plain text!

Comment: What to do if `user.username` is `nil` too?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i have done it and it always works great for me in every situation:
(I suppose that you have added email permission in your code)

*Step 1*

Open **Facebook Framework** folder in `Xcode` and find the `FBGraphUser.h` class

As you see, you have there all the properties that you use from **Facebook Framework**, to take the user details, so add an other property there (copy and paste the code below):

*Step* 2

```
 @property (retain, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> email;
```

And you are good to go!

Comment: Good to go?? where ??? have you read my question? **I need a real email address**. Adding the property will prevent errors that can occur if the NSDictionary won't have an email in it. **BUT** it won't help me figure if the user has an email address associated with the Facebook account or he doesn't and i have to mail him to the Facebook email (username@facebook.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could check for a couple of things:

1. Make sure you are requesting **email** scope permission in the login request dialog:

   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP&redirect_uri=REDIRECT&state=UNIQUE&scope=email
2. Check if the access token you got **actually has email permission granted** with the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: As i wrote, only some users have this problem. I am asking for the email permission (1.) and the access token has the permission according to the Access Token Debugger (2.)

Answer (score 0):

All facebook accounts which are verified through ***Phone Number*** instead of email will get `NULL` for `[user objectForKey:@"email"]`

Answer (score 0):

Facebook won't return the email address if it's not verified.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

This person's primary email address listed on their profile. This field will not be returned if no valid email address is available.