# How do I get the email address of a user using the PHP Facebook SDK v4?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently in the process of integrating Facebook Login with an existing Laravel PHP application. I am using the 4.0 version of the facebook php sdk and have had some success however I have now hit a brick wall.

I need the facebook users email address to create an account for the user and I have got my permission request set up accordingly:

```
$helper = new LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('/login/fb/callback'));
return Redirect::away($helper->getLoginUrl(['email']));
```

The LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper class extends the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper class but overwrites the storeState and loadState methods as Laravel does not make use of the $_SESSION variable.

When I use the facebook login button I am correctly asked for public profile and email permissions and then redirected back to the callback url.

The code I currently have when the callback url is hit is:

```
public function facebook_callback()
{
    $helper = new LaravelFacebookRedirectLoginHelper(url('/login/fb/callback'));

    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

    if($session) {
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');

        $response = $request->execute();

        $profile = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    }
}
```

if I dump the profile variable I see the following info:

```
array (size=10)
  'id' => string redacted (length=17)
  'first_name' => string 'Ben' (length=3)
  'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
  'last_name' => string 'Smith' (length=5)
  'link' => string redacted (length=62)
  'locale' => string 'en_GB' (length=5)
  'name' => string 'Ben Smith' (length=9)
  'timezone' => int 1
  'updated_time' => string '2014-02-15T14:42:46+0000' (length=24)
  'verified' => boolean true
```

As you can see, no email is included. I have tried many different requests to return the users email address but to no avail. Appending ?fields=email to the /me request return only the user id. I can only think that facebook does not believe I have permission to access the users email however when reviewing the granted app permissions from my account settings the email address is included.

Any help would be appreciated, the v4 sdk is fairly new and the documentation is slightly lacking in parts. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you execute it in the Graph Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail&version=v2.0 Do you see an email address in the result?

Comment: Hi Tobi, if I grant the explorer the same permissions as for my application (public profile and email) and then run the query /me?fields=email, I receive back only my id which is what I'm getting when I run the same query on my application. Any ideas as to what is going on? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630972/facebook-graph-api-wont-return-email-address